# Unable to display Gauss Krüger- points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have this list of sampling points and they told me to display them in ArcMap 10.3.1.
This are Gauss Krüger coordinates of soil samples in Austria:

[image]

From a table I use -> "Display XY data" and the Projected Coordinate system "MGI_M34" for Austria.
Unfortunately the points get displayed somewhere in the Indian Ocean and I do not get why?
Can somebody help me?

---

I used country borders and I projected them into MGI_M34 as well. I did try now to add 750000 to the east-coordinates and subtracted 5000000 from the north-coordinates. this is what is written in Wikipedia...
This is the result:

[image]

Afterwards I displayed them and this comes out:

[image]

So the points are in Germany now...
Any idea what that could mean?

Comment: How do you know about the Indian Ocean - did you use a different dataset (e.g. with country borders), and if so, did you make sure to set the correct projection on that one?
Also, there are multiple reference systems for M34, some with false northing, some without (subtract 5 000 000 for your northing). Try to fiddle with those.

Comment: Your northing and easting are flipped

Comment: Your are right!! Sorry, quite a simple solution!!! Thank you very much!!